# wx.python GenBitmapButton SetBackgroundColour only changes the first time

Tags: python, button, wxpython

Still new to using wx.python, so please let me know if I am doing anything wrong. I am trying to create a pseudo Bitmap toggle button. I have 2 or more Bitmap buttons with an initial background of blue, and when one is clicked its background is supposed to change to green. When this happens, all of the other buttons are supposed to change back to blue, but they stay green. Any ideas?

I have recreated my issue below.

BMP image used, but the image doesn't matter: [image]

*Edit: GenBitmapToggleButton suddenly decided to work now, so I will be using that. I am going to leave this up though as this is still a strange bug since it appears to be working on Linux but not on Windows.

```
import wx
import wx.lib.buttons as buttons

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):

        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="Test",size=(800,800))
        panel = wx.Panel(self,-1,name="panel")  

        bmp = wx.Bitmap("Discord.bmp", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY)

        self.Button1 = buttons.GenBitmapButton(panel,bitmap=bmp,pos=(200,400),size=(bmp.GetWidth()+10, bmp.GetHeight()+10),style=wx.NO_BORDER,name="Button1")
        self.Button1.SetBackgroundColour("Blue")

        self.Button2 = buttons.GenBitmapButton(panel,bitmap=bmp,pos=(600,400),size=(bmp.GetWidth()+10, bmp.GetHeight()+10),style=wx.NO_BORDER,name="Button2")
        self.Button2.SetBackgroundColour("Blue")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnClick)

        self.BitmapButtons = [self.Button1,self.Button2]
        self.Show()

    def OnClick(self,event):
        parent = event.GetEventObject().GetParent().GetName()
        name = event.GetEventObject().GetName()

        if parent == "panel":
            for i in range(0,len(self.BitmapButtons)):
                buttonName = self.BitmapButtons[i].GetName()
                if buttonName == name:
                    self.BitmapButtons[i].SetBackgroundColour("Green")
                else:
                    self.BitmapButtons[i].SetBackgroundColour("Blue")


#----------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
      app = wx.App(False)
      frame = MainFrame()
      app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Works fine on Linux. Have you tried using `wx.BLUE` and `wx.GREEN` rather than "Blue" and "Green"? It's a bit of a Hail Mary though.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I was on Windows. I have tried that already, didn't work.

Comment: Try removing the `size=(bmp.GetWidth()+10, bmp.GetHeight()+10)` on one of the buttons.

Comment: Just tried it, didn't change anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option, it uses the `state` of the button and multiple images to achieve what you are doing and I'd argue should be the preferred method of doing it.
Here, I am only using 2 images but you could use 4, one for each `state`
Normal state
Focused state
Selected state
and Disabled state

```
import wx
import wx.lib.buttons as buttons

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):

        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="Test",size=(800,800))
        panel = wx.Panel(self,-1,name="panel")

        bmp = wx.Bitmap("Discord.png", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY)
        bmp2 = wx.Bitmap("Discord1.png", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY)

        self.Button1 = buttons.GenBitmapButton(panel,bitmap=bmp,pos=(100,100),name="Button1")
        self.Button2 = buttons.GenBitmapButton(panel,bitmap=bmp,pos=(200,100),name="Button2")
        self.Button3 = buttons.GenBitmapButton(panel,bitmap=bmp,pos=(300,100),name="Button3")
        self.BitmapButtons = [self.Button1,self.Button2,self.Button3]
        for i in range(0,len(self.BitmapButtons)):
            self.BitmapButtons[i].SetBitmapLabel(bmp)
            self.BitmapButtons[i].SetBitmapFocus(bmp2)
            self.BitmapButtons[i].SetBitmapSelected(bmp2)
        self.Show()
#----------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
      app = wx.App(False)
      frame = MainFrame()
      app.MainLoop()
```

[image]

Comment: The plan was to use the same image and just change the background of each one. This was due to the toggle version not matching the look of the UI.

Comment: It's an option knocked out for my own edification, because your original code works perfectly well on my system. I personally think that this is more elegant but it's your choice.